# Convert IplImage type IPL_LABEL to IplImage type IPL_DEPTH_8U

Tags: types, casting, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.2 and cvBlob in a c++ program and I'm wondering how I can convert a "label" image TYPE IPL_LABEL (unsigned Int) to IPL_DEPTH_8U.
I want to multiply my labeled mask with a "Logical" image (IPL_DEPTH_8U with max intenstiy value=1) by using cvMul.

```
cvMul(labelImg,dest,dest,1);
```

This line always fails because of the type mismatch. Unfortunately I don't know how to correctly cast the labelImg to IPL_DEPTH_8U?

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cvtcolor()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-cvtcolor) also does type conversions of grayscale types